# simple but annoying issue with setting up a switch that is NOT connected to a router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, nas

Having an issue connecting my Windows 10 PC to two NAS devices through a TP link SG108S switch while simultaneously maintaining an Internet connection via WIFI.

My PC is connected to the Internet via a WIFI connection to my router.  I want to also connect to two NAS devices (not connected to the Internet) using my PC's ethernet card via a TP link switch but without losing Internet access on my PC.  I have found that when connected via ethernet I lose my connection to the Internet.

I tried simply connecting my PC to the switch but was unable to see the NAS devices.  I think that they were not getting assigned IP addresses so the local PC couldn't access them.  I then tried including a spare router I had, which did allow me to connect to these NAS devices however when I was connected via ethernet I would no longer be able to access the Internet over WIFI.  I tried to modify TCP/IP setting `Automatic Metric` as I read somewhere that turning this metric on with a number allowed you to control which connection takes precedence.  When I turned this on I then lost the ability to use Nord VPN, it just wouldn't connect to a server.  So I was stuck switching between the network connections on the machine trying to get the systems to play nice but they never could.  I also couldn't have both Internet over WIFI and ethernet connectivity at the same time.

[image]

edit: the router I'm working with is ASUS AC1900 Dual Band 802.11ac gigabit router. the switch is a tp link TL-SG108S.

Comment: Replacing the switch with a router is a bad idea, because that is probably introducing another DHCP server with a conflicting set of IP addresses. Instead try assigning static IP addresses to each NAS unit as well as the (wired) Ethernet port of your PC.

Comment: Seconded; keep to one router and a switch - KISS principle. I recently resolved connectivity issues in my local LAN by [whitelisting the local IP range in NordVPN](https://www.reddit.com/r/nordvpn/comments/vkmt19/how_do_i_whitelist_a_subnet_on_windows_10/). Check your router's GUI, I'd expect to find a DHCP reservation list. Connect one of the devices to the switch, and see if DHCP router makes a reservation. If yes, you should be able to ping & access it when local subnet is whitelisted.

Comment: Oop yeah - you don't specify your Windows version. I used NordVPN with Win10 for a few years, never had a reason to touch the "Automatic metric" checkbox.

Comment: This is a routing issue.  See [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1769143/) You need to set static IPs on PC (ethernet) and NAS and disable `default gateway` on PC so it only uses WIFI for Internet.

Comment: so many thiings going on.. you should troubleshoot. So removing as many factors as possible!

Answer (score 2):

##### WIFI (Internet )

On the WIFI side it is straightforward.  You set it up to get its IP address via DHCP (usually the default) and your router, or modem (depending on your setup), handles the rest.

##### Ethernet (separate network)

For the network connected to your PC's ethernet card you need to define a range of IP addresses and assign addresses in that range to your PC and the NAS devices.  It is also important that your PC's ethernet settings **not include** a default gateway as Windows cannot deal with multi-homed networks and that is likely contributing to your current problems.

##### Define a network

You must use a different network range for your ethernet card than the one used by your WIFI connection.   For example, if your PC's WIFI IP address is `192.168.1.100` it belongs to a class C network `192.168.1.0/24` which includes all IPs in the range `192.168.1.1` to `192.168.1.255`.  None of these addresses can be used for your ethernet card.  You could then use the network range `192.168.50.0/24` which includes all IP addresses between `192.168.50.1` and `192.168.50.255`.

##### Example IP Assignments

| Device | IP Type | Address | Subnet Mask | Default Gateway |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PC | Static | 192.168.50.100 | 255.255.255.0 | none |
| Nas 01 | Static | 192.168.50.110 | 255.255.255.0 | none |
| Nas 02 | Static | 192.168.50.120 | 255.255.255.0 | none |

[image]

At this point, your ethernet card and your NAS devices should all share addresses in the same subnet and know how to find each other.  Traffic from your PC to the Internet will go out through the only gateway defined which is via your WIFI connection.

### IP Setup Instructions

##### Preconditions

1. The network PC connects to for WIFI will be referred to as `MAIN`, and that router as `MAIN Router`.
2. The network created for NAS devices will be referred to as `PRIV`.
3. Your additional spare router will be used for the initial setup and will be referred to as `PRIV Router`.

##### Final Steps

1. EnsurePC's **ethernet** card is **disconnected** from any other device(s) or disabled;
2. Ensure PC's **WIFI** connection is **active** and connected to `MAIN`
3. **Record** PC's **WIFI IP** address (e.g. `192.168.2.214`);
   <sup>[Find your IP address in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/find-your-ip-address-in-windows-f21a9bbc-c582-55cd-35e0-73431160a1b9)</sup>
4. **Disconnect WIFI** from `MAIN` network
5. Connect PC's **ethernet** connection to a LAN port on `PRIV Router`
   <sup><sub>`PC ⟷ PRIV Router` ***OR*** `PC ⟷ switch ⟷ PRIV Router`</sub></sup>
6. Connect NAS01 and NAS02 to LAN ports on `PRIV Router`
   <sup><sub>`NAS0# ⟷ PRIV Router` ***OR*** `NAS0# ⟷ switch ⟷ PRIV Router`</sub></sup>
7. Record the PC's **ethernet IP** address (e.g. `192.168.50.100`);
   <sup>[Find your IP address in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/find-your-ip-address-in-windows-f21a9bbc-c582-55cd-35e0-73431160a1b9)</sup>
8. **Compare** the **WIFI IP** (recorded earlier) and the **ethernet IP** (last step) **omitting** the **last octet**. For example, `100` is the last octet in `192.168.50.100`
9. If **WIFI IP**'s and the **ethernet IP**'s first 3 octets do **NOT match**, skip to **step 13**, otherwise if the first 3 octets **match** continue to **step 10**;
10. Login to `PRIV Router` and define a new network by changing the 3rd octet.  For example, For example, `2` is the 3rd octet in `192.168.2.0/24` so a change to `192.168.3.0/24` or `192.168.50.0/24` or  `192.168.200.0/24` would all work;
11. Now that `PRIV Router` is updated, ensure PC (and NAS devices) request a new DHCP lease. This will likely take place automatically, but you can encourage it by disconnecting and reconnecting the network cable if impatient.
12. go back to **step 7**;
13. Change your PC's **ethernet IP** from dynamic to static using the address detected in **step 7** and set the **subnet mask** to `255.255.255.0` (assuming a class C network).  It is very important that you **do not set** a **Default Gateway**
    [image]
14. Test connectivity from your PC to NAS01 and NAS02;
15. Connect PC's **WIFI** connection back to `MAIN`
16. Test PC's Internet access and NAS access

###### Final Steps

You now have **one** of three ways to finish up:

1. Convert each NAS01 and NAS02 IP from dynamic to static, and then remove `PRIV Router` hardware; ***or***
2. Convert NAS01 from dynamic IP to DHCP server, then remove `PRIV Router` hardware; ***or***
   <sup>With NAS01 as DHCP server, changing NAS02 IP to static becomes optional</sup>
3. Leave `PRIV Router` as part of `PRIV` network;
   <sup>With `PRIV Router` as DHCP server, changing NAS IP addresses to static becomes optional</sup>

Comment: in this method, how do I "know" what the NAS' will be before setting their IP's? Right now I've set up subnet 192.168.2.1 and the switch is connected AND my wifi is staying on (thank you) but how do I go find the NAS connected to the switch now? How do I assign that IP address to something connected to this switch?

Comment: added the hardware models in an edit on the answer above. when you say change the IP address do you mean from within the home router ie login to the main router I'm connected to on wifi then give it its own IP and that should resolve the conflicts? currently i have the ASUS router connected and with the separate IP Address setup you showed me I now have wifi connectivity but i don't know how to connect to the login page of the asus router as nothing shows up on 192.168.2.1 (the range i set for the ASUS router) if i put that URL in the browser I just get a 404